# Using CMD or POWERSHELL to find failed log files

Tags: powershell, cmd, findstr

I have hundreds of log files `import.log`, a successful log file has the last line "`Task finished successfully`".

Each log file is in a separate directory, so my search task is traversing the directories. Reading each  `import.log`, and reporting the full path of a **failed** `import.log`.

A failed `import.log` does **not** contain "`Task finished successfully`".
Or , the last line of `import.log` is not "`Task finished successfully`"

My current solution I find only the successful `import.log`

```
findstr /s /m "Task finished successfully" import.log
```

Please advise how to find the failed log files with CMD tools first choice, POWERSHELL solution is second choice.

Comment: When the string isn't found, the command sets an error.  You can use `||` to specify what to do upon failure.

Comment: thanks to  avery_larry, I created a clunky solution and posted bellow.

Comment: `findstr "Task finished successfully" finds every line that contains at least one of the three words. Use the `/c` switch: `findstr /mc:"Task finished successfully"` to find the complete string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following useful comment from [avery_larry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12055479/avery-larry) . I created a clunky solution that works.

I wrote a batch file `find-failed-imports.bat`

#### find-failed-imports.bat

```
echo off

for /r ..  %%a in (import.l?g) do (findstr "Task finished successfully" "%%a" >nul  || echo %%a failed)
```

Any better solutions welcome.

Comment: My comment to the question also applies here. Alternatively, you can use `find "Task finished successfully"` here (as you don't need the `/m` switch from `findstr`)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's your second choice, but here is a powershell of what you're looking for.

```
$folder = "C:\folder\test\*"
$files = gci -Path $folder -Force -recurse -File -include "*.log"

foreach ($file in $files){
    $content = gc $file.FullName -raw | Out-Null
    if($content -match "Task finished successfully"){
        Write-host $File.Name imported successfully
        # Do more stuff. 
    }
    elseif((Get-Item $file.FullName).length -eq 0){
        Write-host $file is empty.
        #Do more stuff
    }
    else{
        Write-host $file import was unsuccessful.
        #Do more stuff
    }

}
```

You can name the powershell script 'checklogs.ps1' and then call it from a .bat using:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\folder\checklogs.ps1"
```

Comment: added -recurse to this

Comment: I was trying to understand. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a log file where some task is unsuccessful.
When getting the results on file (also in Crtl + c).

I suggest something like this:

---

```bat
@echo off 

set "_err=.\log_error.log" && set "_str=Task.finished.successfully" 

for /r . %%a in (import.log)do findstr "%_str%" "%%~a" >nul || echo=%%~a>>"%_err%"
if exist "%_err%" type "%_err%"|clip & type "%_err%"
exit /b
```

Obs.:

> - **Findstr** will find/check this string **"Task finished successfully"**
> - And can similar find this one: **"Task finished <strike>un</strike>successfully"**

---

For prevent **un**successfully, use: **`"Task.finished.successfully"`**

Use the **[regex](/questions/tagged/regex) `[.]`** == **`wildcard: any character`**

Read more bout **`FindSTR`** **[in this link](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php)**

---

- **Update:** Suggest to check size of files where name == imp*error.log and size > 0

---

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "err=.\log_error.log" && set "str=Task finished successfully"

for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('dir /s /b imp*.log')do if %%~Za neq 0 (
 echo %%~nxa|find /i ".error.log" >nul && echo="%%~fa" >>"%err%"
 ) || ( find /i /v "%str%" "%%~a" >nul && echo="%%~fa" >>"%err%")

(if exist "%err%" type "%err%" | clip && type "%err%") && exit /b
```

---

<sub>Sorry my **English**</sub>

---

Comment: thanks for the contribution. I follow your strategy: I make an `import.error.log` as part of the processing stage. and check the `import.error.log` size > 0 at the analysis stage.

Comment: instead of REGEX, better use the `/c` switch or the `find` command instead. (*Extremely* unlikely to occur, but your REGEX also would match `Taskyfinishedxsuccesfully")

Comment: In this case, i've replace **`in (im*.log)`** to **`in (import.log)`**

Comment: @Stepahn Thank you for comment, i agree with you, but, i improbable occur this string 'Task**y**finished**x**succesfully' in this task where output is predictable.

Comment: @DudiBoy Ops, you need check size of the import.error.log?  I’m not sure if I get understand your last comment.

Comment: Thanks to @It Wasnt Me, I need to check if  import.error.log size > 0. There are errors and therefore the import process failed and need analysis.